# isolating varibles in R programming language with similar letters

Tags: r

I have a `.rds` file and opened that in R as follows:

```
data <- readRDS('test_cl.rds')
```

one of the variables in data would be `orig.ident` which also has multiple items inside it. I need all of those items that start with `'ct '`. in facet start with `ct` and `space` immediately after that. and put them in a new variable called 'data1'. to do so, I tried the following piece of code in R but it does return what I need.

```
data1 <- data[, data$orig.ident == "ct *"]
```

do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you looking for `grepl("^ct\\s", data$orig.ident)`? If not, please post some sample data (eg, using `dput(data)`) to better illustrate your question.